# Combine my own unicode characters in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

`é` is an acute accent letter. `é` can be also represented by `&#769; + e = é`.

However, I was wondering whether I can combine any unicode chars?

For example:

I was looking for a unicode code point for *question mark inside a circle* like in here (picture):

[image]

But I couldn't find any. (I looked [**here**](http://amp-what.com/))

So I was wondering whether I could combine these two:

`?` and `◯` (which is `&#9711;` -- at a larger size of course).

Where `?` is a regular question mark char (`&#63;`), and `◯` is `&#9711;` large circle - geometric shapes.

Is it possible to do so in C#?

## edit like in here

[image]

## where :

[image]

[image]

Comment: è consists of è, it doesn't combine characters  - 00E8 - http://unicode-table.com/en/#00E8

Comment: @Sayse è is ambiguous - it can also be a unicode grave accent combining character with a regular e, i.e. `string s = "e\u0300";`

Comment: @RoyiNamir however, to be pedantic... "è" is not e-acute; that is a grave, not an acute

Comment: @RoyiNamir - appologies

Comment: @Sayse for what ? :-)

Comment: lack of knowledge lol - I didn't realise how flexible the unicode table actually was :)

Comment: I've worked a small bit with a software that was rendering characters in several languages. In vietnamesee you create a combined character by combining a letter with one or several diacriticals. But in European you just use the ready made â è é etc. Why don't you just write a program to try it out? The output will depend on the font you will be rendering in.

Comment: @RoyiNamir again, though, to be pedantic - it is tricky to say "It consists of both --> &#769; + e = é"; the character you have pasted is **just** a single character, `é`. It is, however, possible to get the same visual appearance by using two characters (an e and a combining acute character), but **that isn't the same as the character in the question**. Explicitly: it is not true to say that `"é"` === `"é"`. Honestly, you can copy/paste those and check: they are two different strings. Or as a direct test: `bool b = "é" == "é"; // false`

Comment: @MarcGravell You're right. I mean that the represenation is the same. but of-course you're right. we can check it(IMHO) with `é` (the combination one) and to invoke `toCharArray()` and then reverse the array - and it will go wrong. ( because it consists of 2 chars)

Comment: @Sayse u̡͍̘̭̣ͯ͛̒ͮ͊̈́̃̓̕n͉̥̪̙͈͔̪͈̄͐iͧͯ͗̑͂̚҉͔͚̩̱͕̪ͅc̡̰͎̰͇̯ͥ̓ö̧͇͔̱̟̜̬̟́͞d̵̡̞͎͐̓͐̆̔̓ͮ͗͜ḙ͍̠̗͓̠̟͂ͤͥ̀ͬ́ ̶̛͍̞̪̂ĭ̢̳̟̻̜̱̬ͨͦͫ̆̃̍̐̍͝s̴̞̹̤̤̹̱̠ͭ͐̔ͣ̉͢͢ ͪ̍ͦ̍̆̿̑̈́҉̡̯f̣̯͉͚̫̮̌ͬ̀͟͠ͅú̜̠̼̘͇̜͍͈͌́n̷̸̻̮̊͒̀ͯͮ̚͟

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character Quote: "although as of 2010, few applications support correct rendering of such combinations."

Comment: @MarcGravell - is it wrong that my first thought was Firefox had messed up?

Comment: @mortb That screams out for a <sup>[citation needed]</sup>. At the very least it's useless without knowing which those applications are. I.e. if you're making a webapp, you only care about web browsers, and they all have very advanced font rendering features which might be able to handle what you're doing.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Suggestion: would an icon font do what you're trying to do? (Font Awesome has a circle with a question mark available: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/#icon/icon-question-sign)

Comment: @millimoose: of course your're right my comment needs more info. The work we did was for dsiplaying text in embedded devices and it used fonts and a font renderer based on components from http://www.monotype.com/. I never quite dug into the vietnameese details though...I worked mainly with arabic.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use combining characters on any other character if you like, *but* with the caveat that the font has a large role to play in how it displays. While common diacritics like the acute accent should work for pretty much all Latin characters in most fonts the more obscure ones, like U+20DD Combining Enclosing Circle are a little wonkier. But ?⃝ would be the sequence you need, it just needs font support.

And with that being said, font support is abysmal. All fonts I have here that have a glyph for that character (Arial Unicode MS, Calibri, Consolas) don't honor it's combiningness and just render a large circle next to a question mark. The only one that does render it somewhat correctly is Cambria and Cambria Math, that at least overlap the glyph to the previous one:

[image]

It looks a little better when having the sequence *space, question mark, circle*:

[image]

but still not quite right.

Regarding regular rendering support in a browser:

---

Your browser:

## ?⃝

[image]

---

To accurately answer your question, though: You can just overlay two glyphs in your code by either just placing two labels directly on top of each other or by drawing it yourself. With font and rendering support as poor as in this case this is really something I'd solve through an image. So theoretically it is possible (and from Unicode's standpoint it definitely is because you can represent a circled question mark – but Unicode doesn't concern itself with fonts and rendering) but it's not very practical in most cases.

Comment: Excellent answer; a: it observes that a combining enclosing circle exists, and b: it observes that the font support for this is unreliable (it doesn't work for me, for example).

Comment: Firefox 20 on Windows 7 displays this in pretty much the same way as your Firefox 16 on Win8 example, by the way (except the circle is a little jagged, but that may be for other reasons).

Comment: Note that Chrome tends to have very poor font choices compared to Firefox/Internet Explorer on Windows. It *should* fare better under Linux (but will only be on-par with Firefox then).

Comment: [It looks a lot better in Chrome on Ubuntu](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GUlfc.png) but still not perfect.

Comment: @hammar what is the code you used? please share it via jsbin or something

Comment: @RoyiNamir: That was a screenshot of the characters below where it says "Your browser:" in the answer above.

Comment: Firefox 20 on Ubuntu displays the sign much better than anything in the picture. The question mark is exactly at the centre of the circle(horizontally, vertically it is slightly too high).

Comment: @Bakuriu can you upload a picture ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir [Here](http://i78.servimg.com/u/f78/11/30/47/08/firefo10.png) you can see how it looks like for me.

Comment: Chrome on iOS 6 (on my iPhone) renders it *perfectly*. Circle right around a question mark. Ditto for Safari on iOS.

Answer (score 3):

No, at least not in the sense of combining the way you write.

You will need to create a new font with the graphics of the circle and quotation mark, and you can assign that 'graphic' to one of the locations in a unicode table (substituting the default).

Comment: If anything you should use the PUA for that.